# update or insert in table after report generation in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am generating reports in pentaho and displaying those reports in my dashboard.I am placing a text field with the data from a table. My question here is, can I perform update or insert to the table using pentaho when the text field is edited?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you just need to code it.  Take a look at sparkl which will make that very easy to do.  If you want to see how it's done look at the bissol table editor which is available in the marketplace.